# Is there any reason to proxy a singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, proxy, inversion-of-control

I've seen the following definition in the code:

```
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
public class SomeComponent {
  <...>
}
```

This is a singleton scoped bean. And it seems for me, that there is no reason to proxy it. As far as I understand we should to proxy a bean in case if its scope isn't singleton and differs from a scope of another bean, into which we are going to inject it.

Probably I don't know something. What may be a reason to proxy a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation I found an answer for my question in [an outdated Spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection):

> You do not need to use the `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` in conjunction with beans that are scoped as singletons or prototypes. It is an error to try to create a scoped proxy for a singleton bean (and the resulting `BeanCreationException` will certainly set you straight in this regard).

It answers my question, because `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` is an alternative for `@Scope` annotation. But [current documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) differs from the old one:

> You may also use `<aop:scoped-proxy/>` between beans that are scoped as singleton, with the reference then going through an intermediate proxy that is serializable and therefore able to re-obtain the target singleton bean on deserialization.

It means, now you will not see `BeanCreationException` in case if you will try to define a singleton scoped proxy. But anyway, I don't fully understand the purpose of this vague use-case. So, if anyone understands what this statement means, please, clarify it in comments.

Conclusion: In the most cases there is no reason to proxy a singleton scoped bean.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the scoped proxy: this is what written in [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection).

> Note:
>
> You do not need to use the  in conjunction with beans that are scoped as singletons or prototypes. It is an error to try to create a scoped proxy for a singleton bean (and the resulting BeanCreationException will certainly set you straight in this regard).

Although it refers a pretty old version, but the note is still valid IMO. I've never tried this by myself though.

Having said that, there can be a lot of reasons to proxy the singleton bean, "proxy" is a very broad concept. For example, when we use `@Transactional` its a proxy, there are many other examples. The thing is that this is not a "scoped proxy" which can be treated as a very specific kind of proxy which is apparently not applicable to singletons.